# Why can't I call a generic function with a union type parameter?

Tags: typescript

```
interface A {
    kind: 'a';
    a: string;
}

interface B {
    kind: 'b';
    b: number;
}

type Transform<T extends A | B> = [T, T];

declare function processTransformed<T extends A | B>(arg: Transform<T>): string;
```

I have an array of transformed `A` and `B` that I want to process but the following code doesn't compile.

```
type U = Transform<A> | Transform<B>;

function test(arr: U[]) {
    // Argument of type '<T extends A | B>(arg: Transform<T>) => string' is not assignable to 
    // parameter of type '(value: U, index: number, array: U[]) => string'.
    //   Types of parameters 'arg' and 'value' are incompatible.
    //     Type 'U' is not assignable to type 'Transform<A>'.
    //       Type 'Transform<B>' is not assignable to type 'Transform<A>'.
    //         Property 'a' is missing in type 'B' but required in type 'A'.(2345)
    return arr.map(processTransformed);
}
```

Why am I getting this error and how can I fix it? Are there any materials that I can read about?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This feels like a bug in TypeScript to me, perhaps similar to [microsoft/TypeScript#29479](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29479).  It looks like [inference from mapped types](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#inference-from-mapped-types) isn't properly inferring a union type for the type parameter.  (So far I haven't found an existing issue specifically about inferring unions from mapped types, but it might be out there.  If anyone knows more about this I'd be interested to hear it).

I don't see any fix coming soon, but the workaround mentioned in the possibly-related issue is to explicitly specify the function's generic type parameters if they can't be properly inferred.

In your case since you're passing the function as a callback you have to do something like [eta-expand](https://wiki.haskell.org/Eta_conversion) the function from `f` to `x => f(x)` to allow such specification, like this:

```
function test(arr: U[]) {
  return arr.map(u => processTransformed<A | B>(u)); // okay
}
```

Hopefully that lets you move forward.  Good luck!

[Playground link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4ChnINagAmAXMgORxkDcOycpAzmFKAOY0C+WWoksiKAEKZaBECXIAjarUmkQAVwC2k6J25gAngAcUAFShwQDGAHsoSgDx7kEAB6RxDNMgA+yQQD5kAXmQBtPQAaZD0AXRosQggEABs4KBQYBRAEMGBTEGRtKFMkBgYDIxNzJQhCa1sHCCcXdy8ACgTWUiLjMwtrTwBKRmY2SKwtXWQAVV9Qw3bSy1RvdzaSzq9I5NT0zORIJiaoKFJR-zDukVxEsAUoLISoADolOG0GhV9vHLyIAsWOsor0es8z263XU3CAA)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! The workaround works for me:D